# Data Mismatch Type Error in c# windows Form application

Tags: c#, ms-access

So, I am trying to insert data in a table called prices but an Exception of mismatch data is thrown. This is the code i did to insert

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvMultipleItems.SelectedRows)
        {
            #region Insert Data Into The Database

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", OleDbType.Numeric);
            cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", OleDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@Company"].Value = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PriceStructure", OleDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@PriceStructure"].Value = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemNumber", OleDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@ItemNumber"].Value = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", OleDbType.VarWChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@Description"].Value = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unit", OleDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@Unit"].Value = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", OleDbType.Numeric);
            cmd.Parameters["@Price"].Value = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount", OleDbType.Double);
            cmd.Parameters["@Discount"].Value = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FluidType", OleDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@FluidType"].Value = row.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubContractor", OleDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters["@SubContractor"].Value = row.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount_SubContract", OleDbType.Double);
            cmd.Parameters["@Discount_SubContract"].Value = row.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price_SubContract", OleDbType.Numeric);
            cmd.Parameters["@Price_SubContract"].Value = row.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
```

the database is access and the types are as following: ID= Number, Company= Short Text, PriceStructure = Short Text, ItemNumber = Short Text, Description = Long Text, Unit = Short Text, Price= Number, Discount = Number, FluidType = Short Text, SubContractor = Short Text, Discount_SubContract = Number, and Price_SubContract= Number. Can someone help me tracing the error?

Comment: You are adding parameters in a `foreach` loop? That looks terribly wrong, at least you'll need to do `cmd.Parameters.Clear()` in each iteration...

Comment: you don't need to call `conn.Close();` in the `try` block, since it's already in the `finally` block which is guaranteed to be run.

Comment: You are doing blunder, its not the recommended way of making calls to db like this. `cmd.Parameters["@Price"].Value = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount", OleDbType.Double);`
passing string instead of double? Why don't you do it like
`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price",1.63)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the parameters the wrong way. Dont use `AddWithValue`. Use Add instead:

```
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Numeric);
        cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Company", OleDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@Company"].Value = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        //... and so on...
```

`AddWithValue` is used to add parameters without specifying the data type, and since you are already specifying, the most accurate method will be `Add`, where you do have to specify. A correct use of `AddWithValue` would be:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

Anyway, IMHO `AddWithValue` shouldn´t be used since it can lead you to have problems with data types conversions:

http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

EDIT: You also seem to be having a lot of problem with casting the values as what is expected from the database. You should cast to a similar data type of what is expected. For example:

```
        //THIS IS WRONG!
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", OleDbType.Numeric);
        cmd.Parameters["@Price"].Value = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();

        //THIS IS OK!
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", OleDbType.Numeric);
        cmd.Parameters["@Price"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[6].Value);
```

Comment: Additionally, he's specifying Numeric for types, while providing a string value.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution and it looks like it works but another exception is thrown (can't convert parameter value from string to Decimal). @NicoRiff

Comment: @MohammedAl-A'mri that is because you are casting the wrong way to what is expected from the database... if you have a numeric data type cast as int... not as string

Comment: do you mean that I have to remove the ToString() from Numeric values? @NicoRiff

Comment: @MohammedAl-A'mri you should cast as the correct data type. Leaving only value will be wrong too. See my edit

Comment: I tried That but another exception thrown that is 'System.FormatException' @NicoRiff

Comment: that is because you are having a problem with the imput data on your cells

Comment: thank you @NicoRiff I will do my best to solve that.